# Sequence generation using CUMSUM(TRUE,FALSE) method

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a sequence below and code should be in adaptable form.

```
no_of_col = 12
cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE ), no_of_col/2))
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

Expected Output is:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Here expected output should as shown above.

**Note** the sequence should be generated through `cumsum` command only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), length.out = no_of_col))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
no_of_col = 12
cumsum(rep(c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),no_of_col/4))
```

is this what you are looking for Harvey?

Simplifying things: if you do a simple

```
rep(c(1,0),2)
```

The output is 1 0 1 0
Further, if you do

```
cumsum(rep(c(1,0),2))
```

The output is 1 1 2 2, which is nothing by 1, 1+0, 1+0+1, 1+0+1+0.

You can get required result by the extension of this logic.